# Como criar um novo modelo associado no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relacionamento

Supondo que eu possua o usuário *Admin*, o *Admin* possui um `login_user`, como `system_user`, sendo que esta relação é polimórfica, pois outros tipos de usuários também possuem `login_user`.

Ao criar o formulário de *Admin*, devo acrescentar os campos de `login_user`.

```
<%= form_for(@admin) do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :login_user do |login_user_fields|%>
<%= render partial: 'login_users/fields', locals:{f: login_user_fields, login_user: @admin.login_user, }%>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

A ideia é que, quando criado um novo *admin*, também seja criado um `login_user` para o mesmo, alguma ideia de como fazer-lo?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi acho que você não instanciou o objeto no fields_for.

Sugiro dar uma lida na documentação do método: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Ele explica o que deve ser feito no modelo para aceitar atributos de outro modelo e salvar (accepts_nested_attributes_for).